# Passing values through while loop error

Tags: python, list, parsing, while-loop

I'm having trouble passing values through my while loop. Ive coded below with some pseudocode in Place still I'm unsure how to achieve the result but I have attached my code below to help if it can. The error portion where is passing the values through the while loop

Firstly my double list of values is as below. Which refers to name, easting, northing

```
Stationlist = [['perth.csv','476050','7709929'],['sydney.csv','473791','7707713'],['melbourne.csv','46576','7691097']]
```

And here is the code that I am using:

```
Import math 
global Eastingbase
global Northingbase
Eastingbase=476050
Northingbase= 7709929

Def calculateDistance (northingOne, eastingOne, northingTwo, eastingTwo):
    Base =100000
    deltaEasting = eastingTwo -eastingOne
    deltaNorthing = northingTwo -northingOne

    Distance = (deltaEasting**2 + deltaNorthing**2) **0.5
    If Distance < Base: 
     Return Distance

Def Radius():
1000

L=0
while L <= Len(Stationlist): 
    if calculateDistance(Eastingbase, Northingbase, Stationlist(row L, column 2),Stationlist(row L, column 3)) < Radius: 
        Relevantfilename = StationList (row L, column 1)
        print Relevantfilename
        L = +1
```

My error is that I am unsure how to pass the values from station list into the while loop and then continue the loop. I have tried using double list comprehension I.e [0][1] to pass the name but it won't work. Also adding plus 1 to L doesn't seem to continue the loop. Is there a way to pass all of the values from one row into the while loop and test it.?? I.e pass Perth.csv to Stationlist (row L, column 1), 476050 to Stationlist (row L, column 2) and 7709929 to Stationlist (row L, column 3)

Once that is done then repeat for melbourne and Sydney data

Comment: You are not incrementing L by one. You are setting it to +1. The correct syntax is L += 1

Comment: @andyn thanks for that :) I didn't even realise. My handwritten code in front of me even says L+= 1 yet I haven't transposed it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors/misinterpretations in your code:

- [You should](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) only use upper case names for classes. Infact, it won't even work for stuff like `Import` and `If` (as they are statements, and need to be spelt correctly :p)
- To access elements in a list, you use **indexing** (not **list comprehension**, as you interpreted (that's actually a completely different thing)). For example, `print stationlist[0][2]` accesses the first item in the list, then the third item in the sublist (remember that indexing starts at 0)
- If you want to add one to a number, you do `L += 1` (note the order of symbols). This is the same as `L = L + 1`
- I think you're misunderstanding functions (especially your radius one). All you need to do is `radius = 1000`. No functions needed :).
- Some other Syntax/Indentation errors.

A while loop shouldn't be used here. a *for-loop* is better:

```
for station in stationlist: # Notice the lowercase
    if calculateDistance(eastingbase, northingbase, station[1], station[2]) < radius:
        print station[0]
```

Notice how I use Python's Indexing to get elements from a list. We don't need to include the row, because we are using a for-loop, which goes through each element in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have made the changes u suggested. Regards capitalization that is just sloppy on my behalf and the radius indeed should be a variable not a function. Thanks for the help

Comment: so by replacing the while loop with a for loop it is easier to use and I don't need to search for columns :) wow. This will be of much use in further programming :)

Comment: I have applied the changes but have been thrown an error at deltaEasting =eastingTwo-eastingOne which is... Unsupported operant type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' any ideas as to what the problem is/how to fix it??

Comment: @user2598164 It looks like `eastingTwo` is a string. You can use `int()` to convert a string to an integer (if it can be a valid number). So, you can do `deltaEasting = int(eastingTwo) - eastingOne`

Comment: Of course it is :) thanks. This will also occur for northing as well correct?? Thanks for your help your a python wizz :)!!! Btw I'm new here. Do I have to like do anything to say question solved or closed or anything??

Comment: @user2598164 You can make the values in your list integers instead of strings. Also, feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: @user2598164 underneath the vote count, there should be a tick outline. Simply click it :). If you're having trouble, I posted a link in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You should use `L += 1` to increment the index. But it is not recommended in Python. And also `Radius = 1000` no need to define a function.

```
for each in Stationlist:    
    if calculateDistance(Eastingbase, Northingbase, each[1], each[2]) < Radius: 
        Relevantfilename = each[0]
        print Relevantfilename
```

And I don't why the key words in your script begin with a capital letter. Python is case sensitive so it is wrong. And the `global`s are not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know why the key words are capitalized either. I will just make them consistent and put them as all lowercase and remove the globals :) thanks for the help

Comment: @user2598164 Glad to see :)